# Ver 20.04 LTS trying to play MKV files in VLC

Tags: sound, vlc, mkv

Ubuntu ver 20.04.2 LTS
VLC ver is 3.0.12.1
Updates are current

Using the below list of Preferences changes to VLC I have managed to get some MKV files to play  but not all.

Here is one video that  defeats me
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fUinvtDigVk

Some times only  the sound plays.  Sometimes  I get an error saying the AV1 Decoder is required but not installed.
Supposedly the latest version of VLC shoud have it so I uninstalled and reinstalled and nope, La Rue Sans Joi.

These are the changes I've made to VLC:

In  FILE CASHING (MS)  I set the  value to 1000.

Under ffmpeg I set hardware decoding to Disable

Under ffmpeg I set the Threads  value to 2

Under Audio, I made sure the Enable Audio box is checked

Under Video I selected  OpenGL video output

Under  the Input / Codex icon I set  Pre load MKV files to Always Fix.

I went through the process in Terminal to install BluRay  using wget --no-check-certificate http://vlc-bluray.whoknowsmy.name/files/KEYDB.cfg
That didn'thelp

I'm stuck  this makes no sense. MKV is an ever more popular low loss video format that's been out for almost a decade and  it won't play in the latest players?
I'm stuck
Got any suggestions?
Oh I tried SMplayer  no luck there either.

ALSO
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
ubuntu-restricted-extras is already the newest version (67).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Sooooooo, I already have them too

Comment: Are you using snap or deb version of VLC?  My version is 3.0.9.1 and plays MKV files, no changes to VLC.  Those lemon bars look tasty.

Comment: I have not installed Snap on my system.  I have read  that people have a terrible time with snap VLC and MKV

Comment: Only thing I can suggest right now is remove and try installing version 3.0.9.2-1.  Should be version in software store as deb, snap will probably be newer version.  Think I am still on 20.04.1.  Only problem I have with VLC is if I try to cast and it needs to convert video.