# No audio for some streamed video Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound

So I've researched this a bit and cannot find a satisfactory answer.  In short, some, but not all, YouTube videos play no sound.

***I'm putting this update here to save people from having to wade through that pile of crap I put here earlier.***

Playing around, I manually installed gstreamer1.0-libav.  That fixed part of the problem.  I still have problems with VP9 media.  I have a H.264 (High Profile) video that works fine, but another H.264 (High Profile) that doesn't work.  The one that works is 30fps but the other is 25fps.  There a third video I've been using as a sample that is listed as H.264 that doesn't work either.

I've been using Totem to play these to remove any issue that might be occurring withing the browser.  I've tried using VLC Player, also, but get the same results.

One thing to note is the sound I hear when the video that don't work correctly are playing sounds, for lack of a better term, electronic whispers and squawks.  It's trying to decode the audio; just failing at it.

***End update***  The rest of this is the original post.

I'm convinced that there is just some codec I'm missing or driver that's not updated, but I haven't figured it out and I cannot find anything online specific to this problem.  I've found a ton of similar problems, but they all are about no sound.  I get sound, just not for everything.

By the way, the browser in question is Firefox.

Things I've tried:
installed (and uninstalled and re-installed and rebooted) the ubuntu-restricted-extras.
ensured that Software & Updates > Ubuntu Software checkboxes are all on for main, universe, restricted and multiverse
executed the amdgpu-install script for the Radeon card (and subsequently uninstalled because that screwed up the video)

My hardware settings:  (Sorry, I was going to pare this down, but opted to just throw everything in just in case)

**lspci -nn**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Root Complex [1022:1450]
00:00.2 IOMMU [0806]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) I/O Memory Management Unit [1022:1451]
00:01.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1452]
00:01.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge [1022:1453]
00:02.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1452]
00:03.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1452]
00:03.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge [1022:1453]
00:04.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1452]
00:07.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1452]
00:07.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B [1022:1454]
00:08.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge [1022:1452]
00:08.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B [1022:1454]
00:14.0 SMBus [0c05]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller [1022:790b] (rev 59)
00:14.3 ISA bridge [0601]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge [1022:790e] (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 0 [1022:1460]
00:18.1 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 1 [1022:1461]
00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 2 [1022:1462]
00:18.3 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 3 [1022:1463]
00:18.4 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 4 [1022:1464]
00:18.5 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 5 [1022:1465]
00:18.6 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 6 [1022:1466]
00:18.7 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 7 [1022:1467]
01:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] X370 Series Chipset USB 3.1 xHCI Controller [1022:43b9] (rev 02)
01:00.1 SATA controller [0106]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] X370 Series Chipset SATA Controller [1022:43b5] (rev 02)
01:00.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] X370 Series Chipset PCIe Upstream Port [1022:43b0] (rev 02)
02:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port [1022:43b4] (rev 02)
02:02.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port [1022:43b4] (rev 02)
02:03.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port [1022:43b4] (rev 02)
02:04.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port [1022:43b4] (rev 02)
02:05.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port [1022:43b4] (rev 02)
02:06.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port [1022:43b4] (rev 02)
02:07.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port [1022:43b4] (rev 02)
03:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1143 USB 3.1 Host Controller [1b21:1343]
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1539] (rev 03)
**0a:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cayman PRO [Radeon HD 6950] [1002:6719]
0a:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cayman/Antilles HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6930/6950/6970/6990] [1002:aa80]**
0b:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Zeppelin/Raven/Raven2 PCIe Dummy Function [1022:145a]
0b:00.2 Encryption controller [1080]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Platform Security Processor [1022:1456]
0b:00.3 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Zeppelin USB 3.0 Host controller [1022:145f]
0c:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Zeppelin/Renoir PCIe Dummy Function [1022:1455]
0c:00.2 SATA controller [0106]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [1022:7901] (rev 51)
**0c:00.3 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller [1022:1457]**
```

**sudo lshw -c multimedia**
*-multimedia

```
       description: Audio device
       product: Cayman/Antilles HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6930/6950/6970/6990]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.1
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:79 memory:fcf40000-fcf43fff
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
       physical id: 0.3
       bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.3
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: **driver=snd_hda_intel** latency=0
       resources: irq:81 memory:fce00000-fce07fff
```

**sudo lshw -c video**
*-display

description: VGA compatible controller
product: **Cayman PRO [Radeon HD 6950]**
vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
version: 00
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
configuration: **driver=radeon** latency=0
resources: irq:83 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:fcf20000-fcf3ffff ioport:d000(size=256) memory:c0000-dffff

Comment: You did an apt update and an apt upgrade?

Comment: I did.  In fact, I probably did it half a dozen times.

Comment: I found a related issue here.  It seems like the same issue I'm having, though it's not isolated to VLC Player.   https://askubuntu.com/questions/1314209/ver-20-04-lts-trying-to-play-mkv-files-in-vlc